# Connect two printers over two ISPs

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, printing, printer

I'll try to make it as clear as possible.

So, I have two Different ISP connections, with their own wireless routers, which I used to create two independent networks. Lets call them Network A and Network B

Both networks, have a printer each connected via the ethernet port on these routers and on the Printers.

**Current network configuration**
Internet----> Network A----> Printer A

Internet----> Network B----> Printer B

Currently what happens is that, every time someone at work has to print, they have to switch networks due to a job being executed or printer unavailability on either of the networks.
ie. if a printing job is taking place on Printer A, we need to switch networks to get it to print on Printer B, and so on.

Planned Configuration

Internet---->Network A
                                (need something
                              here to connect                  Printer A &  B
                              them both together)
Internet---->Network B

I would like both the printers to be available on either network. I had planned on using a print server, but since this is the first time I'm attempting something like this, so would like suggestions and ways to get this done.

Thanks in advance. 
Im sorry for any miscommunication

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the situation. How is it possible someone has to switch to a different internet connection to print to a different printer if they are that the same location? Or do they physically move too? Or are both printers at a remote location?

Comment: Both the routers and printers are in the same location. When I mean switch networks, I mean switch wifi connections, to print. So if they were on Network A and tried to print on Printer A, and for some reason they can't, then they would need to switch to Network B and print on Printer B. Thats what I meant

Comment: So basically the network is designed wrong. You would want to create one large network and make the wifi accesspoints connect to the large network, not have different segments. You do not have 2 ISP's. You have 2 internal, different networks.

Comment: So what your saying is, create a LAN with the printers, and then use the Internet connections to connect on to that LAN to print if required.
Just an added question, do you think this would be feasible using a print server in the LAN network or would the LAN just be fine?

Comment: Yeah, if I understand your question correctly, everyone is in the same building, you would want one large network with one or two internet connections going through it, depending on what you want. A printserver can be used but is not required. It determines how much people print and how much control you want over what is being print. For example, if you have 10 clients, it is probably just as easy to look at the person's pc who is having trouble printing. If you have many clients, a printserver allows you to manage what is being print from a central point and thus troubleshoot easier.